# MongoDB/mongoose - Post save hook not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this model/schema:

```
const InviteSchema = new Schema({
  inviter: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account', required: true},
  organisation: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Organisation', required: true},
  sentTo: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account', required: true},
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: new Date(), required: true}
});

InviteSchema.post('save', function(err, doc, next) {

  // This callback doesn't run
});

const Invite = mongoose.model('Invite', InviteSchema);

module.exports = Invite;
```

Helper function:

```
exports.sendInvites = (accountIds, invite, callback) => {

  let resolvedRequests = 0;

  accountIds.forEach((id, i, arr) => {

    invite.sentTo = id;

    const newInvite = new Invite(invite);

    newInvite.save((err, res) => {

      resolvedRequests++;

      if (err) {

        callback(err);

        return;
      }

      if (resolvedRequests === arr.length) {
        callback(err);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

And the router endpoint which calls the helper function:

```
router.put('/organisations/:id', auth.verifyToken, (req, res, next) => {

  const organisation = Object.assign({}, req.body, {
    updatedBy: req.decoded._doc._id,
    updatedAt: new Date()
  });

  Organisation.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, organisation, {new: true}, (err, organisation) => {

    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    invites.sendInvites(req.body.invites, {
      inviter: req.decoded._doc._id,
      organisation: organisation._id
    }, (err) => {

      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      res.json({
        error: null,
        data: organisation
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The problem here is that the `.post('save')` hook doesn't run, despite following the instructions, i.e. using `.save()` on the model instead of `.findOneAndUpdate` for example. I've been digging for a while now but I cannot see what the problem here could be.

The `Invite` document(s) are saved to the database just fine so the hook should fire, but doesn't. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can declare the post hook with different number of parameters. With 3 parameters you are treating errors, so your post hook will be called only when an error is raised.
But, if your hook has only 1 or 2 parameters, it is going to be executed on success. First parameter will be the document saved in the collection, and second one, if passed, is the next element. 
For more information, check official doc: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html
Hope it helps.

Comment: That makes no f***ing sense... But it works now ;S Thanks a lot, you saved me.

Comment: Does this mean if I choose not to specify a hook with a callback taking 3 arguments then my hook with a callback taking 2 arguments is skipped and the regular handler is called with an error?  For example if an error occurs on save, will the error be passed directly to the callback of `.save(cb)`?

Comment: If you declare you hook with 2 arguments in the callback, it will be executed only in succes, but not if an error occurs. Probably you can declare both, one hook with 2 arguments for succes and one with 3 arguments for treating errors. That's a good test :)